# SQL Query with String Builder in C#

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, stringbuilder

I am very new to C#, and I ran into some issues when I try to perform a sql query with stringbuilder.

Here is part of the table named :

```
| ID   | Name      | InternalID |
|:----:|:---------:| :---------:|
| 1    | Emory Lu  | 84765      |
| ...  | ...       | ...        |
| 8    | John Smith| 52455      |
| 9    | John smith| 49         |
| ...  | ...       | ...        |
```

Notice that John Smith are assigned two different InternalID (string type) in this table. In the second record, his last name started with the lowercase "s".

I performed an easy sql query to select an employee's InternalID (string type) when inputting their name：

```
public DataTable findInternalID(string name)
{
    RecordConnection.Open();
    DataTable output = new DataTable();
    OleDbCommand bdCommand = RecordConnection.CreateCommand() as OleDbCommand;
    StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();

    // SELECT InternalID FROM EmployeeList WHERE Name = "(name)"
    x.AppendLine("SELECT InternalID ");
    x.AppendLine("FROM EmployeeList ");
    x.AppendLine($"WHERE Name LIKE '%{name}%'");

    bdCommand.CommandText = x.ToString();
    _dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(bdCommand);
    _dataAdapter.Fill(output);

    RecordConnection.Close();
    return output;

}
```

This block of code works fine for employees only have one record, but for employees with multiple records, it will fill all InternalID records and output at the same time, due to this line:

```
x.AppendLine($"WHERE Name LIKE '%{name}%'");
```

So I tried to change the LIKE keyword into "=" :

```
x.AppendLine($"WHERE Name = '%{name}%'");
```

but this gives me a mistake.

How can I edit my code, so when inputting "John Smith" only outputs "52455" and inputting "John smith" only outputs "49".

Under the main function, I wrote a piece of code to test this function:

```
  string name = "John Smith"; // or John smith
  DataTable output = _accessManager.findInternalID(name);
         
  String message = result.Rows[0][0].ToString(); // Or ROWS[1][0]
  MessageBox.Show(message);
```

BTW, I used MS Access :)

=================Problem solved! ====================

I greatly thank everyone for helping me out. I took everyone's suggestion into account, and here is my final code. I used the `StrComp()` feature which is perfect to performing case-sensitive sql query in MS Access:

```
public DataTable findInternalID(string name)
        {
            RecordConnection.Open();
            DataTable output = new DataTable();
            OleDbCommand bdCommand = RecordConnection.CreateCommand() as OleDbCommand;

            StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder();
            x.AppendLine("SELECT InternalID ");
            x.AppendLine("FROM EmployeeList ");
            x.AppendLine($"WHERE StrComp(Name, @name, 0) = 0;");

            bdCommand.CommandText = x.ToString();
            bdCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", $"{name}");

            _dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(bdCommand);
            _dataAdapter.Fill(output);

            RecordConnection.Close();
            return output;
        }
```

Just a few notes for future reference, if you are using MS Access, then `COLLATE` and `varbinary(MAX)` are not the right features for you.

Comment: **Do not** build queries via string concatenation -- it opens up your application to SQL injection vulnerabilities. Use parameterized queries.

Comment: If using equals instead  of like you don't need wildcards (`%`).  If looking to use a case sensitive filter you should ensure you're using a case sensitive collation in your database (or specify to use one for your query).  As others have said though, try to avoid using string builders to create SQL; rather write complete strings and use parameters to inject values wherever possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. :) Instead of doing the parameter for your like in a string, which is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks especially if the parameter comes from user input, you can use parameterized queries to pass it in safely. More: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a20beb/why-should-always-use-the-parameterized-query-to-avoid-sql-i/

Comment: Your "final code" that "took everyone's suggestion into account" is still vulnerable to SQL injection. You're creating a query parameter, but when you build your SQL you're not referencing it. You're using `'{name}'` to interpolate the name still, instead of `@name` to refer to the parameter.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior the point is I tried it yesterday and it throws me an error ```System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'There is no row at position 0.'```

Comment: @StriplingWarrior I fixed the error and now it's `@name` .Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For starters, you should never build a SQL query by concatenating user provided data into the query string. Doing so makes you vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Instead, you should use query parameters to pass user provided data to your query.

A rewrite of your original function to use parameters might look something like this:

```
public DataTable findInternalID(string name)
{
    RecordConnection.Open();
    var output = new DataTable();
    var bdCommand = RecordConnection.CreateCommand() as OleDbCommand;
    var x = new StringBuilder();

    // SELECT InternalID FROM EmployeeList WHERE Name = "(name)"
    x.AppendLine("SELECT InternalID ");
    x.AppendLine("FROM EmployeeList ");
    x.AppendLine("WHERE Name LIKE @name");

    bdCommand.CommandText = x.ToString();
    bdCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("name", $"%{name}%");
    _dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(bdCommand);
    _dataAdapter.Fill(output);

    RecordConnection.Close();
    return output;
}
```

As for getting a case sensitive query, I can't say that I've actually done that. It looks like `COLLATE` should work, assuming that your database is SQL Server.

```cs
x.AppendLine("SELECT InternalID ");
x.AppendLine("FROM EmployeeList ");
x.AppendLine("WHERE Name = @name COLLATE Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS");
```

Or, perhaps casting to `varbinary(MAX)` to compare the bytes?

```cs
x.AppendLine("SELECT InternalID ");
x.AppendLine("FROM EmployeeList ");
x.AppendLine("WHERE CAST(Name as varbinary(MAX)) = CAST(@name AS varbinary(MAX))");
```

Also, as one last note, you don't really need to use a `StringBuilder` at all. You could just use a verbatim `string` with the `@` identifier if you want to format the statement across multiple lines.

```cs
string commandText = @"SELECT InternalId
FROM EmployeeList
WHERE Name = @name COLLATE Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS";
```

Comment: This is a great suggestion. I deleted my earlier answer as it wasn't cognizant of SQL injection concerns (Thanks much to @DanielMann for the SQL safety advocacy).

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestion. I do like the idea of not using a stringbuilder, unfortunately the place where I work requires us to use a stringbuilder specifically in this file for readability :(

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you just need case-sensitive search, try this one!

`x.AppendLine($"WHERE Name = '{name}' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS ");`

In MS-Access, try this one!

`x.AppendLine($"WHERE StrComp(Name, '{name}', 0) = 0");`

Comment: I downvoted this answer because you should not give people advice on how to build security vulnerabilities into their software.

Comment: I appreciate your response, but I tried your code and it still gives me an error. Do you have any thought of how can I perform the case sensitive search correctly?

Comment: Can you paste here your error?

Comment: @EmoryLu what database are you using?  Is it SQL Server as assumed here, or some other DB (MySQL, Postgres, MS Access, etc)?

Comment: @JohnLBevan It's MS Access, Thank you

Comment: Ah - in that case I believe you want `strcomp` with the third argument (compare) given as 0 (`vbBinaryCompare` https://www.codevba.com/visual-basic-source-code/vb-string/checking_if_two_strings_are_equal.htm#.Ygvo2TT7RHY): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/strcomp-function-a9a4531e-3b2a-4218-b139-f7442bc10b96

Comment: @MateenArif Thank you, I used the StrComp() feature and it worked well.